# How can a lattice attack be applied to ECDSA signatures?

Tags: cryptanalysis, dsa, side-channel-attack, lattice-crypto

The aim is to check if it is possible to break the ECDSA cryptosystem under the following criteria.

- Suppose that each **ECDSA signature** is generated by using the **GLV method** for point multiplication (the random nonce $k$ used in each signature is decomposed into $k_1$and $k_2$).
- For every ECDSA signature, I can obtain few bits (least significant bits, most significant bits, ...) of the respective $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Is it possible to carry out a lattice attack to gain the value of the underlying secret key ($\alpha$)? If yes, then can you explain the attack in detail?

PS: I have a beginner level understanding of ECDSA and lattices.

Comment: It is a theoretical question. I tried searching if it is possible to do that, and more information on the topic. I searched various research papers and the internet. For example, I have confirmed that a lattice attack can be applied when I have few bits of $k$ for every signature (this is generally the case when **GLV method** is not used). But in my case I have few bits of $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Comment: Yes, this paper is exactly for your question. http://www.iacr.org/conferences/asiacrypt2014/5-3_GLVGLS%20Decomposition,%20Power%20Analysis,%20and%20Attacks%20on%20ECDSA%20Signatures%20With%20Single-Bit%20Nonce%20Bias.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can do. There are many lattice attacks, using your second assumption, to ECDSA (which also applied to DSA). For instance see  [Smart and Howgrave-Graham](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=A3522D6371B33FD55DDADD9566D6779C?doi=10.1.1.95.797&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [Shparlinski and Nguyen.](http://www.di.ens.fr/~pnguyen/pub_NgSh02.htm) All the lattice attacks base on finding small solutions (for the ephemeral key $k$ and the private key $a$) to the signing equation $sk-ra\equiv H(m)\pmod q.$ If you have enough signatures (i.e. enough $k_i$) then you construct a linear system $\bmod q$ and then a suitable lattice and if you have enough bits from every $k_i$ and $a$ and enough messages you can solve the CVP problem. Also you can apply Coppersmith method to the signing equation.

Comment: I've quickly edited your answer to improve your signing equation and I've also improved your style a bit. If you don't like my edits you can either edit again or roll my edits back by clicking on the "edited...ago".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But $k_1$ and $k_2$ in my question do not mean random nonces of different signature instances. Please read my comment below the question.

Comment: As far as I know, If you have few bits ( $\ll \sqrt{q})$ from two ephemeral keys there is not any attack.

Comment: it seems like you misunderstood my question/comment. $k_1$ and $k_2$ are not two ephemeral keys. They are related to a single ephemeral key ($k$) by the relation: $k \equiv (k_1 + k_2 \lambda) \mod n $. Here, $\lambda$ is the endomorphism of the curve.

Comment: Ok, you have two blocks  of contiguous bits of one ephemeral key.  You can apply the attacks given by the references I wrote in my answer. But you need  enough bits. Almost bits(k1)+bits(k2)$\approx bits(n)/2$ (of course with $n$ here, you mean the prime order of the subgroup generated by a point of your curve, usually in ECDSA is written $q$).

Comment: @111 I don't think that I have contiguous bits of one ephemeral key too. $k_1$ and $k_2$ are related to $k$ as I mentioned in my previous comment. But it doesn't imply that knowing certain bits of $k_1$ and $k_2$ is equivalent to knowing certain bits of $k$ (and that exactly is my problem).  What you said about the bitlength of $k_1$ and $k_2$ is correct. But I don't get it as to how I can apply the attack mentioned in your references. I will look into them again. Maybe I am missing something very small (or maybe it's not possible).